# Как применить модификатор Geometry Nodes в Blender?

Tags: 3d, blender, export, моделирование

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при попытках применить модификатор **Geometry Nodes** ничего толкового не выходит - остается пустота (т.е. когда я применяю модификатор, моя модель просто пропадает). Также, пробовал делать через ***Make Instances Real*** - но такой вариант не подходит, так как в модели появляется больше одного миллиона полигонов! Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне делать и как применить этот модификатор?

P.S Модель была полностью сделана при помощи Geometry Nodes, в Blender 3.0.0.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете добавить *Realize Instance Node* перед конечным выводом геометрии (*Group Output*, вход *Geometry*). Таким образом вся геометрия (экземпляры, их копии и т.п.), полученная до этого узла, будет превращена им в действительные данные о геометрии. После этого примените модификатор *Geometry Nodes* к вашему объекту.

(Источник: [официальная документация Blender](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/realize_instances.html))